# Filling in low area to create platform with concrete / leveling

Tags: concrete, self-leveling-concrete

I have some steps going off the back door of a house (from the 50's) that I'm working on and am attempting to help prepare for market / sale (USA).

The steps go down to an easement which runs perpendicular to the steps.

The problem is, the steps go down (not all the way to ground level) and then there is another step back up. So, essentially, the lowest step has two higher steps on either side of it.

```
(Side View)
                                          | Door to house
                                          |
                                        |
                              __________|
                             |
_______              ________|
       |  Low Area  |
       |_(8in deep)_|
```

On the back side of the low area, we have more concrete that is level with the 2 surrounding steps, on the front side, there is nothing currently - it's just open.

I need to fill this low area so there is a single platform.

The concrete that is there is likely also from the 50's - Somewhat cracked, and certainly imperfect.

I'm not concerned about perfection as this is a formality, but I would like to fill in the low area and then smooth the top and I have a short timeframe to do it in.

I'm looking for suggested methods. Here is my rough-draft plan:

- Take 2x4s and cap the "open" end of the low area by using concrete screws and screw into the areas surrounding the low areas. This will act as a barrier for new concrete.
- Get Quikrete high pressure concrete, mix and pour into low area. (4 CuFt already purchased)
- Shortly thereafter (24 hours?) use self leveling concrete to smooth out the entire platform so it looks decent.

Is this a viable plan? I've never poured concrete before, but am handy and can pick things up - I just want to make sure I get the right things and do the right process.

Answer (score 1):

A picture of the site would be helpful for some of the forming questions.

First, I would recommend using one full piece of forming lumber instead of stacked 2x4.

Second, if you are handy,  it should be pretty simple to screed your concrete across the two steps, trowel and broom finish it, and skip the self leveling layer.